# How can I change styling on a button when it's clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, elementor

I have three buttons that are linked together, kind of like tabs. I want to make the name of the currently selected button appear in bold. So, when I click a button, I'd like its name to be bold, while the others remain as regular text.

IDs:
button1
button2
button3

I need to do this using Javascript, and I'm using WordPress Elementor. Here's what I used:

Button widget - (for the 3 buttons)
Text widget - to display the tab content when I click a button
HTML widget - to connect the buttons and text widget

[image]

I know it might seem odd since I could just use the tabs widget, but there's another functionality I need.

Any suggestions, please?

I'm giving this a shot, but I'm not sure where to put it.
`button1.style.fontWeight = '900';`

Here are some codes to provide you with insight.

```
button1.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  tab1.style.display = 'flex'; // Show tab1
  tab2.style.display = 'none'; 
  tab3.style.display = 'none'; 
   resetButtonStyles();
  button1.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
 
});

// Add click event to button2 to show tab2 and hide tab1
button2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  tab1.style.display = 'none';   // Hide tab1
  tab2.style.display = 'flex';
  tab3.style.display = 'none'; 
   resetButtonStyles();
  button2.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  
});

button3.addEventListener('click', function() {
  tab1.style.display = 'none';  
  tab2.style.display = 'none';
  tab3.style.display = 'flex';
   resetButtonStyles();
  button3.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a code snippet using your current functions along with the font weight addition you are trying to add. You're on the right track in that you need to turn on the styling for the clicked button and tab while turning off the styling for the two other buttons.

I built a simple example of these three functions in action:

```js
tab1.style.display = 'flex';
tab2.style.display = 'none';
tab3.style.display = 'none';
button1.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
button1.style.fontWeight = '900';


button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  tab1.style.display = 'flex';
  tab2.style.display = 'none';
  tab3.style.display = 'none';
  //resetButtonStyles();
  button1.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  button1.style.fontWeight = '900';
  button2.style.fontWeight = '300';
  button3.style.fontWeight = '300';

});

button2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  tab1.style.display = 'none';
  tab2.style.display = 'flex';
  tab3.style.display = 'none';
  //resetButtonStyles();
  button2.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  button1.style.fontWeight = '300';
  button2.style.fontWeight = '900';
  button3.style.fontWeight = '300';

});

button3.addEventListener('click', function() {
  tab1.style.display = 'none';
  tab2.style.display = 'none';
  tab3.style.display = 'flex';
  //resetButtonStyles();
  button3.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  button1.style.fontWeight = '300';
  button2.style.fontWeight = '300';
  button3.style.fontWeight = '900';

});
```

```html
<button id="button1">Example button 1</button>
<button id="button2">Example button 2</button>
<button id="button3">Example button 3</button>
<p id="tab1">Example tab 1</p>
<p id="tab2">Example tab 2</p>
<p id="tab3">Example tab 3</p>
```

Something I would also suggest would be to make a single function which turns off the styling of all the buttons and then turns on the styling of the current button and tab; like this:

```js
button1.style.fontWeight = '900';
button1.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
tab2.style.display = 'none';
tab3.style.display = 'none';

function toggleTab(tab, button) {
  var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab');
  for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    tabs[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].style.fontWeight = '300';
  }
  tab.style.display = 'flex';
  button.style.fontWeight = '900';
  button.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
}
```

```html
<button id="button1" class="button" onclick="toggleTab(tab1, this)">Example button 1</button>
<button id="button2" class="button" onclick="toggleTab(tab2, this)">Example button 2</button>
<button id="button3" class="button" onclick="toggleTab(tab3, this)">Example button 3</button>
<p id="tab1" class="tab">Example tab 1</p>
<p id="tab2" class="tab">Example tab 2</p>
<p id="tab3" class="tab">Example tab 3</p>
```

This second suggestion isn't required, but could help simplify your code.

Comment: In addition to combining functions, toggling a CSS class is generally preferable to setting a bunch of styles in a script.

Comment: Hi @Nick, thanks for trying this. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me, and I'm not sure why. The code runs perfectly on its own, but when I added the rest of the codes I needed, it didn't work. Any ideas? Here's my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/YannaCuesta/wkosyp4h/12/)

Comment: Tips I'd give would be to ensure you aren't repeating things in your code while also ensuring you have the correct classes and ID's added to your HTML elements. Looking at your JSfiddle, it doesn't seem to have the JavaScript function I've made for you added.

Comment: Hi @NickFriesen, everything's great now! I switched to using the HTML widget for buttons instead of the buttons widget, just like what you did. I also added the ID and class, following your lead, and it fits perfectly with the JavaScript code you provided. Plus, it solved the problem I had with the clicking function. In my old code, when I clicked the button, it would go back to the top, but now it stays in the same place. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: So glad to hear Yanna! Happy to help and I'm glad you got things working!